# Warning numerical expression has >1 elements: only the first used

Tags: r, datatable, sum, row, multiple-columns

I have a dataset as follows:

```
Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov b
1.0 9.0 4.0 5.3 6.4 3.4 2.5 4.3 2
5.0 6.0 9.0 2.3 5.8 2.3 6.5 5.2 3
8.0 4.0 6.0 0.7 5.2 1.2 2.2 6.1 4
2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 7
3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 8
4.4 4.1 5.1 6.1 7.1 8.1 9.1 6.8 6
5.6 5.0 3.2 4.2 5.2 1.2 2.2 3.2 5
6.8 5.9 8.9 2.3 3.3 5.7 4.7 3.7 5
8.0 6.8 9.8 4.8 5.8 6.8 7.8 8.8 5
9.2 7.7 7.7 2.8 3.8 4.8 5.8 6.8 6
```

I want to add a column sum `data$sum=rowSums(data[data$b:8])`. But getting a warning `numerical expression has 2124 elements: only the first used. Please let me know a better method.

Comment: Can you show us the output you expect?

Comment: `data$sum <- sum(data$b[1:8])` <-- is this what you want?

Comment: Are you sure about a colSum?  That should create a row. if you're looking to sum up each row, use `data$sum=rowSums(data)`. `data$b:8` makes no sense

Comment: for each row the elements for sum will differ for example for the first row the sum will be from 2:8 then 3:8 and so on based on the number in the b column. That's why I used data$b:8.

Comment: @AlbertRajan Please put the additional information in your question (not in a comment), i.e. **edit your question:** https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49249572/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution based on your comments:

```
data$sum <- NA # important to create the column before the for loop
for (rowIdx in 1:nrow(data)) {
   startCol <- data[rowIdx, "b"]
   data[rowIdx, "sum"] <-  sum(data[rowIdx, startCol:8])
}
```

You need to use a for loop / apply statement to achieve this because you cannot specify a different starting column for each row using the `[` subset operator.

Two things can happen when you use `[]` without a comma depending on your data structure:

- If `data` is a `matrix` it will treat the entire matrix as a single vector, where each column occurs one after another. For example, `data[1:15]` will return the 10 values in the "Apr" column then the first 5 values in the "May" column.
- If `data` is a `data.frame` it will use the indices to look up columns. That is `data[1:5]` is the same as `data[,1:5]`. The reason for this is that a `data.frame` is really a `list()` underneath the hood, where each column is an element of the `list()`.