# Dynamic row addition

Tags: r, for-loop, datatable, sum

I have a dataframe as follows I need to create a column sum. For each row the sum will be from the month of action.

```
Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Action On
4.0 2.0 3.0 2.0 1.5 1.0 0.5 4   July
3.0 4.0 1.0 7.0 2.0 3.0 1.0 2   August
3.0 3.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 6.0 September
1.0 1.0 0.5 0.3 0.3 0.5 0.5 2.0 October
0.5 1.0 0.4 0.1 0.1 0.3 0.3 3.0 July
0.4 3.0 0.0 0.2 0.2 0.1 0.1 9.0 September
1.3 5.0 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.2 0.2 7.0 November
2.2 7.0 0.6 1.0 0.6 0.4 0.4 1.2 July
```

Please let me know the best code. I created a column  converting the month to numeric and used a for loop as  follows:

```
for(rowidx in 1: nrow(conshead)) {
   startcol=conshead[rowidx,"b"]
   conshead[rowidx,"sum"]=sum(conshead[rowidx,startcol:8], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

still there is this error

> Error in startcol:8 : NA/NaN argument.

Please share a better code.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249572/warning-numerical-expression-has-1-elements-only-the-first-used

Comment: In the data you presented there is no column `b`. Eventually you can put the result of `dput(conshead)` in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what your after?

```
> m1 <- data.frame(Jul = c(1,4,6),
+                  Aug = c(3,5,9),
+                  ActionOn = c("July", "August", "July"))
> 
> m1
  Jul Aug ActionOn
1   1   3     July
2   4   5   August
3   6   9     July
> 
> m1$sumofinterest <- colSums(m1[,match(substr(m1$ActionOn, 1, 3), colnames(m1))])

> m1
  Jul Aug ActionOn sumofinterest
1   1   3     July            11
2   4   5   August            17
3   6   9     July            11
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)

# reading your data
df <- read_table("Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Action On
4.0 2.0 3.0 2.0 1.5 1.0 0.5 4   July
3.0 4.0 1.0 7.0 2.0 3.0 1.0 2   August
3.0 3.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 6.0 September
1.0 1.0 0.5 0.3 0.3 0.5 0.5 2.0 October
0.5 1.0 0.4 0.1 0.1 0.3 0.3 3.0 July
0.4 3.0 0.0 0.2 0.2 0.1 0.1 9.0 September
1.3 5.0 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.2 0.2 7.0 November
2.2 7.0 0.6 1.0 0.6 0.4 0.4 1.2 July")
```

the code is:

```
df %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(SUM=colSums(.)) %>% 
  bind_cols(df %>% select_if(is.character))
```

output:

```
  # A tibble: 8 x 10
  #  Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   SUM `Action On`
  #  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
  # 1 4.00     2. 3.00  2.00  1.50  1.00  0.500  4.00 15.4  July       
  # 2 3.00     4. 1.00  7.00  2.00  3.00  1.00   2.00 26.0  August     
  # 3 3.00     3. 1.00  0.500 0.500 1.00  1.00   6.00  6.80 September  
  # 4 1.00     1. 0.500 0.300 0.300 0.500 0.500  2.00 11.5  October    
  # 5 0.500    1. 0.400 0.100 0.100 0.300 0.300  3.00  5.60 July       
  # 6 0.400    3. 0.    0.200 0.200 0.100 0.100  9.00  6.50 September  
  # 7 1.30     5. 0.300 0.400 0.400 0.200 0.200  7.00  4.00 November   
  # 8 2.20     7. 0.600 1.00  0.600 0.400 0.400  1.20 34.2  July
```

grouping by month would be:

```
df %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(SUM=colSums(.)) %>% 
  bind_cols(df %>% select_if(is.character)) %>% 
  group_by(`Action On`) %>% 
  summarise(SUM_per_month=sum(SUM))
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#   `Action On` SUM_per_month
#   <chr>               <dbl>
# 1 August              26.0 
# 2 July                55.2 
# 3 November             4.00
# 4 October             11.5 
# 5 September           13.3
```